# 301 Redirect via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make 301 redirect via htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /page_one http://site.com/
```

But this code also redirects every children link of **/page_one**

For example it also redirects **site.com/page_one/article** to **site.com/article**

How to make 301 redirect exactly from **/page_one** to **site.com/** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive uses prefix matching as illustrated in the following example:

> ```
> Redirect /service http://foo2.bar.com/service
> ```
>
> If the client requests *http://myserver/service/foo.txt*, it will be
>   told to access *http://foo2.bar.com/service/foo.txt* instead.

Try using [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/page_one$ http://site.com
```

Change `302` to `301` after testing. And may be you need to remove the trailing `/`.